# ajax can not retrieve data in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I want to fetch data from database by checking data. I send data as json file but it does not work. In network it shows not data to retrieve. Though when without ajax I can retrieve data from database. when I change dataType:'json' it does not hit the controller. when this change to 'html' then fired alert().

```js
This is my ajax code
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ret_pass').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = {
                u_mail      : $('#email').val(),
                u_ques      : $("#security").val(),
            };
            console.log(data);
            url = $('#ret_form').attr('action');
            //console.log(url);
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:url,
                data: data,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(res){
                        alert(res.msg);//says undefined
                        console.log(res.msg);       
                },
                error: function(res) {
                alert(res.msg);
                alert('error');//also says error!
            },
            });

        })
    })
```

```html
This is controller code
public function ret_pass()
 {
        header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $u_mail = $this->input->post('email');
            $u_ques = $this->input->post('security');
            $cond = array(
                'u_mail' => $u_mail,
                'u_ques' => $u_ques
            );
            $query = $this->db->where($cond)->get('tbl_user');
            $checker = $query->result_array();
            //if (count($checker) > 0) {
            if (!empty($checker)) {
                //var_dump($results);
                //echo json_encode ($results);
                die(json_encode(array('success' => true, 'msg' => $checker)));
            } else {
                echo "bad search";
                die(json_encode(array('success' => true, 'msg' => 'invalid search')));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are not sending any data back from the controller

```
public function ret_pass()
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $u_mail = $this->input->post('email');
        $u_ques = $this->input->post('security');
        $cond = array(
            'u_mail' => $u_mail,
            'u_ques' => $u_ques
        );
        $query = $this->db->where($cond)->get('tbl_user');
        $checker = $query->result_array();
        //if (count($checker) > 0) {
        if (!empty($checker)) {
            //var_dump($results);
            //echo json_encode ($results);
            echo (json_encode(array('success' => true, 'msg' => $checker)));
        } else {
            //echo "bad search";
            echo (json_encode(array('success' => true, 'msg' => 'invalid search')));
        }
    }
}
```

By doing this, your Ajax call will get a JSON Response of what you have encoded and you shall be able see it in your Javascript Alert.

Comment: doing that but only ajax error function fired. that means it does not send back any data.

Comment: in the error function , add this : { alert(res.responseText) } and see what the error is